# Referencing Images in Xamarin Forms User Control/Class Library

Tags: c#, dll, user-controls, xamarin.forms, class-library

I've built a user control for my Xamarin Forms projects, starting with a Xamarin.Forms Class Library. The user control contains an image file that I've added to the Class Library project in an "Assets" directory. Within the user control code's XAML I'm simply referencing the image as...

`<Image  Source="Assets/ImageFile.png"/>`

I'm thinking there's no need for platform-specific code here since the image file is local to the Class Library project and compiled into it.

When I reference the DLL in a Xamarin Forms project, everything works as expected...EXCEPT, there's no image. It's as if the Class Library can't see it.
I've played around with the path, but the result is always the same: no image.

However, if I drop the image file into the Xamarin Forms project (i.e., into the Assets directory in UWP), the image appears just fine -- even though I'm still referencing the Class Library through the DLL.

What am I missing? Surely I can embed the image within the DLL, yes?

Comment: what is the structure of your project?  A shared project + UWP project?

Comment: The user control is in a "Class Library (Xamarin.Forms)" (...how it's listed in VS2017, at any rate), and the main project is a "Cross Platform App (Xamarin)" with a PCL.  Looks like there are details for embedding images within class libraries buried deep within the Xamarin web site:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the image is included within your DLL:

You need to set the ***Build Action: EmbeddedResource***.

> To embed an image in a project, right-click to add new items and select the image/s you wish to add. By default the image will have Build Action: None; this needs to be set to Build Action: EmbeddedResource.

If you need to know where to set this:

> The Build Action can be viewed and changed in the Properties window for a file.

You can read more [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/).